# Connect Arduino to an external microSD card reader

Tags: sd-card, sd

I have a camera with a microSd card reader that is the only output type.
I want to read the microSd when the camera makes a photo.
How can I read it with an Arduino?
Duplicating the reader connections and join it to my Arduino microSd reader?
Or I can try to connect to the circuit (its very very small)?
Do you think I can put an ESP8266 to the camera?

Thanks for all!!!

Comment: Have a look into "Processing" and the camera libraries for it.

Comment: Or do you want to achieve something like: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-OV7670-Camera-Module-with-Arduino/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what the goal is and/or the current goal is beyond the capabilities of an Arduino

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot**

SD cards cannot be shared between masters in operation, and it is unsafe to disconnect the card from the camera with an electronic switch when the camera is not expecting that.

Nor is an ordinary Arduino fast enough to passively snoop the data being written to the card by the camera (while a card will let an Arduino write to it quite slowly, any camera would do so far, far faster)

Nor is an ordinary Arduino able to do much of anything meaningful with the image files produced by a typical camera in real time.

Nor can an ESP8266 while running Arduino-based software; it apparently does have some high-speed I/O capabilities but that would require low-level rather than Arduino-port-based programming.

For all practical purposes, you'd need to power off the camera, remove the card, and place it in the Arduino reader.

Comment: I guess no is an answer as well :) I highly agree that it doesn't really make sense nor seems practically possible. A lot of camera's can be directly interfaced with an PC, that would be a better option.

Comment: For what it's worth, I personally believe that the question is not on topic for the Arduino site because the fundamental problem is that SD cards are not designed to be shared, and already voted accordingly to close it.  But since we seem to be very slow about closing such questions went ahead and posted a comprehensive explanation as to why it's not achievable with an Arduino or Arduino-based technology.

Comment: True, but wel it's a question on Arduino. If it was possible, it would be on topic? But I agree it's not really answerable in any further way than you just did.

Comment: the camera is in other circuit and I need to extract the images/videos

Comment: As already explained, it doesn't really matter what you need, SD cards simply cannot be shared.  You will have to find another way to share data, or power down both devices and move the card between them.